# Where in Quran it's specified that a person can will one-third of their assets for charity?

Tags: islamic-basis, inheritance

I read that a person can not ask for more than one-third of their assets to be spent on charity in their will, and the remaining two-third should be divided according to Quran's laws.

But I can't find the verse saying this.

Can you please tell me if this has been specified in Quran or not?

Answer (score 4):

The possibility of making an optional bequest (وصية) and distributing the remainder according to the prescribed shares is present in the Quran.

> من بعد وصية يوصين بها
>
> ... after any bequest they [may have] made
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:11-12](https://quran.com/4/11-12?translations=20)</sup>

It is also within the Quran that restraint is place on the bequest so as not to deprive the legal heirs:

> من بعد وصية يوصى بها أو دين **غير مضار**
>
> ... after any bequest which was made ... **as long as there is no detriment [caused]**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:12](https://quran.com/4/12?translations=20)</sup>

The specifics (limiting to no more than a third) is not in the Quran but in hadith:

> الثلث والثلث كثير
>
> One-third, yet even one-third is too much
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/55/7)</sup>

Note that various madhabs allow for making and enforcing a bequest of more than a third with the permission of the heirs.